# What sequence of events happen inside FPGA as we power on?

Tags: intel-fpga

I am using Cyclone V FPGA from Intel on my board. It is configured using external flash.

I would like to understand what happens (sequence of events) inside the FPGA when I power on the board.

Any pointers on this doubt will be helpful?

P.S. I am not sure whether this question make any sense or not. Relative new to Hardware Design.

Comment: The FPGA datasheet does not have this info?

Comment: FPGA datasheets are a lot more complicated than regular IC datasheets; often the most important information about a core/family is found in application notes and reference manuals. [Cyclone V Device Handbook](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/cv_5v2.pdf) chapter 7 Configuration, Design Security, and Remote System Upgrades in Cyclone V Devices ; see also https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683375/current/configuration-sequence.html which seems to be the official intel/Altera source document